# d3.js barchart plugin animation methods

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am having issues trying to build this jquery based d3.js barchart plugin.

1. the bars are displaced to the left, not sure why
2. the bars are not updating to new data.

I've tried to get the bars to animate - but not had any success.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/161/

Here is the animate bars function

```
animateBars: function(data){

                        var svg = d3.select(methods.el["selector"] + " .barchart");

                        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                                        .data(data);

                            bars            
                            .enter().append("rect")
                              .attr("class", "bar")
                              .attr("x", function(d) { return methods.x(d.letter); })
                              .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
                              .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.frequency); })
                              .attr("height", function(d) { return methods.height - methods.y(d.frequency); })
                              .transition()
                                .duration(300)

                            bars
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)      

                            bars.exit()
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)                      
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the transition for new bars in your jsfiddle. I hope it reveals the functionality of transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/893/

How it works: After it sets the initial height and y value, it adds a transition to the end height and y value.

```
bars            
 .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return methods.x(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(0); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return methods.height - methods.y(0); })
 .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return methods.height - methods.y(d.frequency); });
```